# Mac OS app which runs php script

Tags: php, macos

I have a php script which runs using terminal and then it keeps running. It dumps data from a remote server into local directory by creating .txt files. Now I want to create a Mac app which once open will run this script. 
I dont want to use terminal I just want to create an app which when starts runs the script and as long as the app is running the script would be running.

My question is is there any way we can run a php script in a Mac application.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `YOURNAME.command` file, put what you want to execute inside and make it executable with `chmod +x YOURNAME.command`

The file when you double click will execute what you put inside.

Comment: ah ! learn every day ... thks @MaximK

Comment: @MaximeK i wll give it a try. Lets hope it works